# How can I get an HP Officejet to stop claiming ink cartridges are defective every time I replace them?

Tags: printing, printer, hp-officejet

Here's my problem. I have an HP Officejet 6600 e-All-in-one. About two months ago it displayed that my magenta ink cartridge was low. I began hunting around for an ink cartridge and found a magenta one I hadn't thrown out. Wondering if it had at least enough ink to print out the document I was working on, I installed it. The printer said that the cartridge may be low on ink and asked if I was sure I wanted to install it. I said yes, and the system began checking the ink cartridge like it always does. It then threw up an error that my **blue** ink cartridge was defective. I reopened the cartridge door, removed the blue ink cartridge, and reinstalled it. The system now stated that not only the blue cartridge, but the yellow cartridge was defective now.

Annoyed, I logged onto HP's website and after half an hour of trying canned solutions, I called HP (who conveniently told me as I was calling them that my printer was out of warranty, I still called because they claim that ink cartridges are under a separate warranty). After waiting for a tech support rep, they had me clean the ink cartridge's connection head (most likely how it communicates with the printer to attempt to prevent refills) and remove and reinstall them half a dozen times. Finally, they stated that due to my *printer* being out of warranty, the only thing they can tell me to do is go buy new ink cartridges and try them. If they didn't work, they said, I would then, and only then, be sent a new printer. I was annoyed. Right on the side of my ink cartridge it claimed it was under warranty. I was then given a prepared speech in legalese that stated that essentially the ink cartridge warranty is worth less than a can of beans. At least the rep didn't make me pay for the call. I got the problem fixed by taking the cartridges up to Staples where I bought them (and the printer) and explained my problem. They gave me replacement cartridges which worked great.

Until yesterday.

I was told yesterday by my printer that my magenta cartridge was low. I went out and bought a brand new, genuine HP, replacement cartridge. After installing it, the printer claimed that my blue cartridge was defective. I have replaced every cartridge except my XL black one since the error last time. I am completely clueless as to what to do. I've Googled this error and heard tons of people's complaints about HP forcing high ink prices down people's throats with fancy lock-out systems. How can I get my printer to print without requiring me to replace ink cartridges I know are full?

tl;dr: Every time I replace an ink cartridge in my HP printer, it claims my other cartridges are defective. What can I do?

Comment: If you've tried cleaning it and replacing the cartridges, then replace the printer, and don't buy another HP (or better, avoid all cheap inkjet printers - you get what you pay for, and the OJ6600 was/is a CHEAP printer).

Comment: It sounds like the printer head itself is to blame.  Since the printer is out of warranty you likely could go out and purchase a NEW printer for the amount of money it would take to purchase a new printer head for your printer ( this statement assumes it can even be replaced ).

Comment: Do yourself a favor. Keep the Officejet for the scanner module and buy yourself a cheap inkjet (Canon and Epson, to name some, have nice offers). The new printer, including ink will probably be cheaper than new HP cartridges or repair on the HP. Besides HP ink has a nasty tendency to dry out if not used for several weeks. This is less of a problem with Canon and Epson. These days I consider cheap inkjets as disposable as their cartridges. If anything goes wrong with it just replace it. Life is too short, and the printers to cheap, to waste time and aggravation on it.

Comment: @Nathan2055 You cannot "Keep the Officejet for the scanner module" because it locks up everything, even scanning and faxing that do not require ink, if there is a low ink problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before throwing it out the window, it's worth taking a pencil eraser and rubbing off the ink head contacts.

Ambient humidity whether you live near the ocean or if your particular printer was mildly defective... can tarnish copper contacts.

A pencil eraser rubbed as gently as you'd erase a word off paper can rejuvenate electronic devices from cell phone batteries to your printer.

I can't hurt and you'll be surprised how effective it can be.

In every HP I own, I can still find ink in places you wouldn't think,  take a dry (non Puff's moistened) kleenex, paper towel or toilet paper and rub the printers cartridge tray for any ink and this will be your culprit.

If you have ink accumulation, using high concentrate rubbing alchol dabbed paper towel to dlean it then immediately dry it will rejuvenate the printer

These are worth trying before kicking it out your window, but kicking an HP printer can be immensely satisfying .